# AWS Serverless for Microservices and true "pay-as-you-use"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

**Premise**
I'm trying to come up with the right choice of AWS construct for a containerized microservice (set of microservices in fact) deployment. The application will have an average load of 50% through the day and little to nothing during the night and at very specific times in the day(which is not always pre-determinable) there is a burst of high-volume requests. Also, it's not a super-busy set of microservices ( in other words, 2 instances of 1VCPU and 8GB RAM will just be fine )

The fargate compute option seems to be a better option for this type of a setup, except of course that

- When my application has little or no load during the night, I will still be charged for the full 1VCPU and 8GB (which according to me is not true "pay as you use" as I might be using only 0.05 or 0.25 VCPU  - hypothetical numbers )
- The only way to get around this is to write some redefinition strategies myself: watch Cloudwatch events and recreate the Fargate tasks with lesser VCPU. However, it will have some extra overhead in terms of deployment time (even if I ensure staggered deployments, it still means a 'lot of work' each time there is a material event). Is there a better way to do this or is there a more 'truly' out of the box pay-as-you-use arrangement that can let you consume resources in a range continuously based on what you actually are using at that moment without having to jump through the hoop?
- Lastly, the purist in me still cannot reconcile in theory the fact that a microservice isn't a 'task' really and use of a Fargate compute option doesn't sound intuitively right to me even if I could think of a microservice as an extreme case of a task running permanently Costwise, am I better off using EC2 as some options seem to get me a cost that is lesser than Fargate (I'm aware of the additional responsibility in maintaining/patching those EC2 instances )?

Comment: I would still go with multiple Fargate "task" with 0.25VCPU and 2GB memory or 0.5VCPU and 4GB if you want it to be "serverless". Otherwise, you can also use Opswork  time-based scaling or EC2 schedule scaling

Comment: The Serverless Pay-as-you-use compute service is AWS Lambda. Fargate is "serverless" but **not** Pay-as-you-use. If you want Pay-as-you-use you should be looking into converting your app to run on AWS Lambda.